# GitHub maven CI error Missing commit <commit hash>

Tags: maven, github, github-actions

I am trying to set up the standard maven CI pipeline (so just mvn package) on GitHub, but I always get the error "Error: Missing commit ", where  is referencing the second last commit (so not the commit that this run is checking, but the commit before).

I already reset the whole build pipeline by deleting it and setting it up freshly again, but that didn't help.

The maven.yml is the standard maven.yml created by GitHub, but here it is:

```
# This workflow will build a Java project with Maven
# For more information see: https://help.github.com/actions/language-and-framework-guides/building-and-testing-java-with-maven

name: Java CI with Maven

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Set up JDK 16
        uses: actions/setup-java@v2
        with:
          java-version: '16'
          distribution: 'adopt'
      - name: Build with Maven
        run: mvn -B package --file pom.xml
```

Thank you in advance!

EDIT:
This is the complete error log (now also with -X):

```
Error:  Missing commit 3914bff7919d762d5e6708304167e2047133595d -> [Help 1]
org.eclipse.jgit.errors.MissingObjectException: Missing commit 3914bff7919d762d5e6708304167e2047133595d
    at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.WindowCursor.open (WindowCursor.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.revwalk.RevWalk.getCachedBytes (RevWalk.java:853)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.revwalk.RevCommit.parseHeaders (RevCommit.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.revwalk.MergeBaseGenerator.next (MergeBaseGenerator.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.revwalk.StartGenerator.next (StartGenerator.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.revwalk.RevWalk.next (RevWalk.java:414)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.revwalk.RevWalk.isMergedInto (RevWalk.java:391)
    at edu.kit.ipd.lez.maven.ChangeLogMojo$$anonfun$findBranch$2.apply (ChangeLogMojo.scala:100)
    at edu.kit.ipd.lez.maven.ChangeLogMojo$$anonfun$findBranch$2.apply (ChangeLogMojo.scala:99)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply (TraversableLike.scala:778)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach (Iterator.scala:750)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach (Iterator.scala:1202)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach (IterableLike.scala:72)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach (Iterable.scala:54)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach (TraversableLike.scala:777)
    at edu.kit.ipd.lez.maven.ChangeLogMojo.findBranch (ChangeLogMojo.scala:99)
    at edu.kit.ipd.lez.maven.ChangeLogMojo$$anonfun$1.apply (ChangeLogMojo.scala:52)
    at edu.kit.ipd.lez.maven.ChangeLogMojo$$anonfun$1.apply (ChangeLogMojo.scala:52)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.map (List.scala:273)
    at edu.kit.ipd.lez.maven.ChangeLogMojo.execute (ChangeLogMojo.scala:52)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:567)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Error:  
Error:  
Error:  For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
Error:  [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MissingObjectException
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

(The URL points to a 404 Page)

Comment: Please rerun with `-e` or `-X` to show the full message.

Comment: @JFabianMeier done. As an information: the lez plugin is something our university uses to automatically test submissions that we upload, package commit messages into a nice file and so on. But setting up GitHub CI is not part of the task, just something I want to understand and get right personally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess the thing is with the checkout. From the checkout action description:

```
# Number of commits to fetch. 0 indicates all history for all branches and tags.
    # Default: 1
    fetch-depth: ''
```

So you probably just fetch one commit and that's it. Other commits then cannot be found.

Comment: This was indeed the issue.
Note for other people who read this: you have to specify fetch-depth: 0 for actions/checkout@v2 action.